# Динамическое изменение таблицы

Tags: php, javascript

У нас есть  заявки игроков для старта игры. К примеру игра шашки, в нее могут играть 2 человека. 
Пользователь создает предложение поиграть и ждет соперника, когда соперник присоединятся, то пользователь стартует игру.

<b>Итак к примеру у нас есть таблица:</b>

```
<table id="proposal">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>№</th>
                    <th>Игрок</th>
                    <th>Опции</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Пользователь/или ожидание</td>
                    <td>Действия</td>
                </tr>

                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Пользователь/или ожидание</td>
                    <td>Действия</td>
                </tr>

            </tbody>
        </table>
```

Уже сгенерированная  с помощью чих пых пых.

Вот у нас 1 пользователь создал заявку и 1 колона таблицы будет с данными 1 пользователя, вторая колонка будет с ожиданием 2 игрока.

Далее к примеру происходит SSE запрос и возвращает нам данные, что присоединился 2 игрок

Далее у нас есть SSE запросы, которые проверяют присоединился ли второй игрок. К примеру игрок присоединился и сервер вернул JSON, где есть такой массивчик:

```
  ['users'] =  array(
                                'user' => 'avatar',
                                'sort' => 0,
                                'root' => 1,
                              ),
                    array(
                                'user' => 'avatar',
                                'sort' => 1,
                                'root' => 0,
                              )
```

Наша задача добавить в нужный <tr> данные пользователя которые вернул сервер. 
Тоесть:

```
// вот у нас 1 пользователь, который создал заявку 
                <tr> 
                    <td>1</td>
                    <td>Nepster</td>
                    <td>Вверх, Вниз, Кик</td>
                </tr>

// вот тут у нас присоединился 2 пользователь  
                <tr>
                    <td>2</td>
                    <td>Сюда нужно добавить значение [user] из пришедшего с сервера массива </td>
                    <td>тут посложнее, стоку действия генерирует php</td>
                </tr>
```

<b>Для этого мне посоветовали:</b>
http://underscorejs.org/#template

Но честно говоря вообще не представляю как можно это использовать?

И второй момент, когда пользователь создавший заявку меняет местами игроков (это актуально, когда идет игра на пары).

Приходит массив, где есть поле sort, которое отвечает за сортировку игроков

```
['users'] =  array(
                                    'user' => 'avatar',
                                    'sort' => 0,
                                    'root' => 1,
                                  ),
                        array(
                                    'user' => 'avatar',
                                    'sort' => 1,
                                    'root' => 0,
                                  );
```

Посоветовали использовать плагин для сортировки таблиц или http://underscorejs.org/#sortBy

Но тут тоже не могу понять как связать массив, который пришел с сервера с sortBy данной библиотеки.

Подскажите пожалуйста, кто в курсе как это можно реализовать?

Answer (score 1):

Если без всяких библиотек, то можно просто сериализовывать JSON на клиенте и потом джаваскриптом загонять данные в нужные ячейки через innerHTML

Comment: Реализовал полную отрисовку таблицы через js по входящим json данным. Сэкономил куча кода.